# How can i encode and decode two number in a single integer using bit manipulations?

Tags: c++, bit, bitset

I was learning about bit manipulations then I thought of this. Say I have two numbers, First in the range of [1,6] and second in the range of [0,3]. Now the first number can take max 3 bits to be stored and the second can take 2 bits to be stored. How can I use one int32 to store both of them in it. Thanks.

Comment: You also might be interested in looking at [bit feilds](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encode:

```
// a : range of [1,6], bit0 ~ bit2
// b : range of [0,3], bit3 ~ bit4
// c : encoded int32
c = 0;
c |= (a | b << 3);
```

Decode:

```
a = (c & 0x00000007);
b = (c & 0x00000018) >> 3;
```

Comment: Have an upvote: your code is more professional than mine, especially `a | b << 3` which is a touchstone for your operator precedence knowledge.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks, but I liked your idea of multiplication and division. (guess it's edited now) It looked simpler than this one.

Comment: That's how I think of it in my head but I think using bitwise operators is a bit less idiosyncratic. Your answer still remains superior as you've taken care to document it. (Funny how we put the two numbers in different places. Is that how the endianness battle started?)

Answer (score 2):

`int32_t composite = first_number << 2 | second_number;` would do it.

`second_number` then occupies the two least significant bits, and you can extract it with `composite & 3`.

`first_number` occupies the three bits to the "left" of that, and you can extract it with `composite >> 2`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to encode more than two numbers?

Comment: Sure it is. You just use more bitwise operators for the extraction. The answer of @nglee generalises more readily.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need two numbers packed into one int, instead of bit manipulations you might want to use a [bit fields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field). That way you could store two fields in space of one int-field and access them by names.

Comment: I am trying to send data over the network and It has to be an int. I have some restrictions here. Thanks.

Comment: @Ankitsinghkushwah it can take exactly the size of int worth of storage, just be careful with signed/unsigned. You can check it here: http://cpp.sh/6q73k maybe it will help you another time :)

Comment: Note that the layout of bitfields is implementation-specific. There is no requirement that a struct containing two small fields must fit in an `int`. That's what's typically done, but it is not guaranteed.